# INSERT and RETURNING vs. NULL returning trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

For the sake of readability I'll provide a simplified version of the database.

Let's say I have a base table:

```
CREATE TABLE base_table
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT requests_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And one that inherits it:

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
()
INHERITS (base_table);
```

On the base table a trigger is set:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_row()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO child_table VALUES (NEW.*);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER row_insert_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON base_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_row();
```

The purpose of such triggers in my database is to partition the base table according to some rules. It works as expected but it has a significant downside. An `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO base_table (name) VALUES ('test') RETURNING id
```

Will insert a row but it won't return anything since the trigger function returns `NULL`. I tried several solutions to this problem but, frankly, I wasn't satisfied with neither of them:

1. Using a rule instead of a trigger.

A solution to the above problem could be a simple rule, such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE row_insert_rule AS
  ON INSERT TO base_table DO INSTEAD
  INSERT INTO child_table VALUES (NEW.*)
  RETURNING id;
```

However In real life I would like to perform more operations than this simple insert, which will require to use a stored procedure. I don't know how to use it in a rule with returning:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE row_insert_rule AS
  ON INSERT TO base_table DO INSTEAD
  SELECT id FROM some_procedure(NEW)
  RETURNING id;
```

Will obviously fail as using `SELECT` and `RETURNING` isn't valid pgsql syntax. Omitting `RETURNING` in the rule causes `INSERTs` with `RETURNING` to fail.

1. Two triggers - `BEFORE` and `AFTER`

In this solution the `BEFORE` trigger looks like the one provided earlier, except it does not return `NULL` but `NEW` - so it is usable with `RETURNING` but it inserts a row to `base_table`. The `AFTER` trigger can be used to delete that row afterwards. I consider this solution unelegant - it looks weird, causes problems with the sequence on id, etc.

1. Ommiting `INSERT` altogether

Instead of using `INSERT` statement on `base_table` I could execute a stored procedure which will insert a row in the appropriate table. This solution will be in my opinion the best performance-wise but it would require the applications using this database to "remember" not to use `INSERT` on this table and rely on a provided stored procedure - it is a requirement I can't fulfil because of the architecture of our systems.

1. Selecting current value of the id sequence in the same transaction.

The same problem as in the previous solution - requires the application to do something more than just insert data to the table.

Is there a simple, elegant and - most importantly - fast (in terms of performance) solution to my problem? Or - it is possible to modify my solution no 1 to work with `RETURNING` properly?

Comment: Agreed, haven't found it before. Also - thanks for the answer, I'll probably use it.